# Cant find my Url adress or there is something wrong with my programming

Tags: php, html

I have created a database (on phpmyadmin) and a form using php and html but I can't seem to find my databases URL address or there is something very wrong with my form... and It is saying   Error -1 - Bridge response error, please check the API docs or this ajax response. What does it mean?
Here is the code:

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Database</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
            $dbhost = localhost;'localhost:id674442_wommath';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'passroot';

            $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

            $fir_name = $_POST['fir_name'];
            $sur_name = $_POST['sur_name'];
            $li_points = $_POST['li_points'];
            $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];

            $sql = "UPDATE First_name ". "SET Sur_name = $sur_name ". 
               "WHERE fir_name= $fur_name" ;
            mysql_select_db('test_db');
            $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysql_close($conn);
         }else {
            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">First_Name</td>
                        <td><input name = "fir_name" type = "text" 
                           id = "emp_id"></td>
                     </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">Surname</td>
                     <td><input name = "sur_name" type = "text" 
                        id = "emp_id"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">life_points</td>
                     <td><input name = "li_points" type = "text" 
                        id = "emp_id"></td>
                  </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">xp_points</td>
                        <td><input name = "xp_points" type = "text" 
                           id = "emp_salary"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
            <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Please help!(my students want their website finished!!)

Comment: Sorry, but what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: My problem is...    I can't find my URL address or my html or php is wrong. So when i fill in my form and press update is says Cant find Url address. But I am shore that my URL address is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated the code, there were lot of errors in the code. Also, if you are using php7, always use mysqli not only mysql.

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Database</title>
   </head>

   <body>
      <?php

         if(isset($_POST['update'])) {


            $dbhost = 'localhost';
            $dbuser = 'root';
            $dbpass = 'passroot';

            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

            if(! $conn ) {
               die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
            }

            $fir_name = $_POST['fir_name'];
            $sur_name = $_POST['sur_name'];
            $li_points = $_POST['li_points'];
            $xp_points = $_POST['xp_points'];

            $sql = "UPDATE First_name SET Sur_name = '".$sur_name."' WHERE fir_name= '".$fir_name."'";

            mysqli_select_db('test_db');
            $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );

            if(! $retval ) {
               die('Could not update data: ' . mysqli_error());
            }
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";

            mysqli_close($conn);
         }
         else {


            ?>
               <form method = "post" action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
                  <table width = "400" border =" 0" cellspacing = "1" 
                     cellpadding = "2">

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">First_Name</td>
                        <td><input name = "fir_name" type = "text" 
                           id = "emp_id"></td>
                     </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">Surname</td>
                     <td><input name = "sur_name" type = "text" 
                        id = "emp_id"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td width = "100">life_points</td>
                     <td><input name = "li_points" type = "text" 
                        id = "emp_id"></td>
                  </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100">xp_points</td>
                        <td><input name = "xp_points" type = "text" 
                           id = "emp_salary"></td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td width = "100"> </td>
                        <td>
                           <input name = "update" type = "submit" 
                              id = "update" value = "Update">
                        </td>
                     </tr>

                  </table>
               </form>
               <?php
         }
      ?>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is still not working... it is still showing this when I press update.                Not Found
The requested URL /< was not found on this server.    But I am sure my URL address is right.

Comment: In html form, update action with <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>

Comment: Where do you want me to put it? Because it hasn't changed anything? ;-(

Comment: Your query got resolved already..accept the answer and close this question

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
$dbhost = localhost;'localhost:id674442_wommath';
```

Why is there semicolon?

Set `$dbhost` to `"localhost"` and it will work.

Comment: I have set my code to                                                                          $dbhost =" localhost":'localhost:id674442_wommath';                                          but it still isnt working...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about your  `$dbhost`  parameter .

You must set it correct value.

And if you can share more details helping will be easy to you .

If you are working on `localhost`  use must write something like this :

`$dbhost = 'localhost';` or `$dbhost = '127.0.0.1';`

And make sure your Apache server is using  port 80 and if its different you must write it after the localhost or ip like this :

`$dbhost = 'localhost:port number';` or `$dbhost = '127.0.0.1:port number';`